# Jasmine preload necessary javascript files before running the testing spec

Tags: jquery, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I got 2 javascript files:

1. `jquery.js` which I want to write unit test for.
2. `jquery.test.js` which contains jasmine describes that aimed to test the jquery functionality.

Is there any way to preload the jquery.js in jquery.test.js or somewhere else so I can reference the `$` symbol?

Answer (score 1):

karma `files` config option should have all the files loaded for when test is executed.

https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html